# how to find non unique combinations of two variables in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have two columns in Excel that identify individual records (ID and code). Some of these may occur multiple times. For some records, the code may be missing. And some IDs belong to multiple codes. I need to find these IDs that have non unique associations with a given code, and show what those are.

Minimal example:

```
ID    code
K151  ABC
K152  BCD
K153  EFG
K154  
K151  ABC
K154  HDG
K153  EFF
K151  ABC
K153  EFG
```

So I need to have a list (possibly with the number of occurences):

```
ID    code  freq
153   EFG   2 
153   EFF   1
154         1
154   HDG   1
```

It is fairly easy to do something similar using a Pivot Table, but note that e.g. K151 - ABC occurs 3 times, and it should not be listed, just those IDs that have multiple codes. Also, in the pivot table the codes are collapsed under the ID as parent category and they are not shown side by side.

It is also OK, if the non-uniquely coded IDs are flagged in the original table in a new variable, and then these records can be filtered manually using the flag.

```
ID    code   flag
K151  ABC    0
K152  BCD    0
K153  EFG    1
...
K153  EFF    1
...
```

I need to find a solution in Excel (2013), not VBA or anything else, and ideally the solution should also be compatible with LibreOffice Calc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flagging will be simple.

[image]

Formula in `C2` downwards:

```
=COUNTIF($A:$A,"="&A2)<>COUNTIFS($A:$A,"="&A2,$B:$B,"="&B2)
```

Formula in `D2` downwards:

```
=IF(C2,COUNTIFS($A:$A,"="&A2,$B:$B,"="&B2),0)
```

For OpenOffice we need `SUMPRODUCT` because `COUNTIF` will not count if blank.

Formula in `C2` downwards:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$20,"="&A2)<>SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$20=A2)*($B$1:$B$20=B2))
```

Formula in `D2` downwards:

```
=IF(C2,SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$20=A2)*($B$1:$B$20=B2)),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy and paste the first two columns in a different location.
2. Select the data and Use Remove Duplicates tool in the Data tab.
3. Start third column and use `COUNTIFS` for multiple column criteria to get the count of each row.